# Can't open apps on Ubuntu 22.02 from contabo VPS

Tags: gnome, 22.04, desktop-environments, xrdp, desktop-apps

The desktop looks empty and icons doesn't show up at all. I can't open settings, file, power, etc. I have no trouble opening the terminal. This is the initial startup file for xrdp:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# xrdp X session start script (c) 2015, 2017, 2021 mirabilos
# published under The MirOS Licence

#Improved Look n Feel Method
cat <<EOF > ~/.xsessionrc
export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
export XDG_DATA_DIRS=
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
EOF

# Rely on /etc/pam.d/xrdp-sesman using pam_env to load both
# /etc/environment and /etc/default/locale to initialise the
# locale and the user environment properly.

if test -r /etc/profile; then
        . /etc/profile
fi

test -x /etc/X11/Xsession && exec /etc/X11/Xsession
exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession
```

And this how the desktop looks like:
[image]

Comment: That script might not be setting up systemd/dbus properly

Comment: How do you typically set up the systemd/dbus? Shouldn't it just work by default usually?